# Jupyter notebook Variable Inspector for pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The Variable Inspector extension for Jupyter notebooks has a "json object defining the libraries to load, the delete/remove kernel commands to delete a variable, and finally the commands to refresh the list of variables."

From the default json object below, I can see that the default includes 'python' and 'r'.

```
{  'python': {            library: 'var_list.py',            delete_cmd_prefix: 'del ',            delete_cmd_postfix: '',            varRefreshCmd: 'print(var_dic_list())'        },  'r': {            library: 'var_list.r',            delete_cmd_prefix: 'rm(',            delete_cmd_postfix: ') ',            varRefreshCmd: 'cat(var_dic_list()) '        }}
```

What text would I add to this json object so I could define the library to load, view, delete, and refresh the list of variables for a pySpark notebook?

Comment: to be added, discussion on [Github](https://github.com/jfbercher/jupyter_varInspector/issues/1)

Comment: Could you give more details on how you setup your pyspark kernel?

Comment: @jcb91 I did mine on a windows machine.  To see how I did it, have a look at https://gist.github.com/clayms/d442a08f4d7177e056a6d208d4c3cf52   Others have told me they have had success with Cloudera VM or a pre-configured Docker container.